# mysql_real_escape_string, query and number of rows

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

```
include("lib/config.php");
include("lib/mysql.php");

if ($_GET['action'] == "loginsignup") {
    $error = "";
    if(!$_POST['email']) {
        $error = "an email address is needed";
    } else if(!$_POST['password']) {
        $error = "a password is needed";
    } else if (filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
        $error =  "please enter a valid email address";
    }

    if ($error != "") {
        echo $error;
        exit();
    }

    if($_POST['loginactive'] == "0") {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE email = '".mysql_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."' LIMIT 1 ";
        $result = mysql_query($link,$query);

        if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) $error = "that email address is already taken.";
    }

    if ($error != "") {
        echo $error;
        exit();
    }
}
```

so here is the code im trying to verify if there are any errors and if there is an email in my database that has the same one thats being signed up so im getting these errors

`mysql_real_escape_string()` expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given

`mysql_query()` expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in

`mysql_num_rows()` expects parameter 1 to be resource null given in

and i really i tried going back and forth with mysqli and mysql and they both have the same errors

Comment: Are you setting the variable $link?

Comment: Good god, have you even bothered to _read_ the documentation of the function you use? http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php You swapped the order of the arguments!

Comment: And whilst reading that documentation you should also notice that _huge_ read deprecation warning. It is there for a reason!

Comment: He might be using a lower version than 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing as argument a variable which is either declared or initialized to mysql_real_escape_string(), which is causing it to return an unexpected result, causing mysql_query() & mysql_num_rows() not receiving the expected parameters.

Hope it helps!